# PHP form submit with validation & Bootstrap issue

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am really new to PHP and bootstrap and pretty much everything. I've been trying to follow several tutorials about making a form with bootstrap and using PHP to send the form via email. I've gotten parts to work and others not. What I have been trying to do is get the form to show error messages under each form element if parameters haven't been met. Then, once everything is filled out correctly the form submits without refreshing the page but DOES show a success message. I've been combining several tutorials but this one is the one I'm trying to emulate with the error and success messages. https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/working-bootstrap-contact-form/

Currently the form submits and emails IF everything is filled out correctly but loads the .php file and sits there at a blank screen. If the name isn't entered then it doesn't send the email and still just loads the .php file with a blank screen. Any help would be appreciated! Below is my PHP and HTML snippet

HTML

```html
<form name="adoptionForm" method="post" action="phpForms/adoption_doc.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
                <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
                <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
            </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                Send Message
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP

```html
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "stackoverflowTest@gmail.com";

/* POSTS INFO */
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];


/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

$subject = "$name has sent you a message";

$message = "

Someone has sent you a message using your contact form:

Name: $name
Email: $email
Address: $address
City: $city
State: $state

";

// Check if name has been entered
if (!$_POST['name']) {
 $errName = 'Please enter your name';
}

/* Send the message using mail() function */
if (!$errName && !$errEmail) {
    if (mail ($myemail, $subject, $message)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
}
    

?>
```

Comment: "PHP form submit without refreshing current page" --> AJAX.

Comment: go for `ajax`. it will give you what your desire. thanks.

Comment: http://teachingyou.net/php/simple-php-contact-form-using-ajax/ for example

Comment: Take a look here https://github.com/bootstrapbay/contact-form/blob/master/index.php

Comment: And if you're using jQuery, you might want to take a look at the jQuery Validator plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this code, and it is an updated copy of the code you are trying to use that should work.

You will need to change the action on the form to whatever name of your page is.

```
<?php
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $to = 'stackoverflowTest@gmail.com';
    $subject = "$name has sent you a message";
    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    } else {

    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    } else {
        $from = $email;
    }

    // set body of message to be sent

    $message = "
        Someone has sent you a message using your contact form:

        Name: $name
        Email: $email
        Address: $address
        City: $city
        State: $state
        ";

    //Check if address has been entered
    if (!$_POST['address']) {
        $errAddress = 'Please enter your street address';
    } else {
        $address = $_POST['address'];
    }

    //Check if city has been entered
    if (!$_POST['city']) {
        $errCity = 'Please enter your city';
    } else {
        $city = $_POST['city'];
    }

    //Check if state has been entered
    if (!$_POST['state']) {
        $errState = 'Please enter your state';
    } else {
        $address = $_POST['state'];
    }

// If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errAddress && !$errCity && !$errState) {
        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $from)) {
            $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
        } else {
            $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
        }
    } else {
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error in checking.</div>';
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Bootstrap contact form with PHP example by BootstrapBay.com.">
        <meta name="author" content="BootstrapBay.com">
        <title>Adoption Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <h1 class="page-header text-center">Adoption Form</h1>
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
                                <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>"; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
                                <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>"; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Street Address</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Your Street Address">
                                <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errAddress</p>"; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="city" class="col-sm-2 control-label">City</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Your City">
                                <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errCity</p>"; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="state" class="col-sm-2 control-label">State</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" name="state" placeholder="Your State">
                                <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errState</p>"; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                                <?php echo $result; ?>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>   
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So I got this all to work using qcsites help. HOWEVER... the odd issue is that it only works when the PHP is embedded in the html file. If I try to have the form action reference another page with just the PHP in it, it fails. and just shows me a blank page. It works perfectly if I include all the php in the html document. Any ideas? Should I just leave it that way? Is it bad form? Thanks all!

Comment: You should be able to create a separate file called send.php or something and post to that if you want, though as long as you are displaying an obvious success or error message on the form page, posting back to it is fine. The goal is to let the user know if the message was sent successfully.

Comment: Thanks so much qcsites! You have been a big help. I still can't get it to work by making the PHP separate but I'm just leaving it be for now. Thanks again!